# Issue on writing spark streaming results to HDFS or local filesystem

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

using Java API, I wrote a spark streaming application that process and print results correctly and now I want to write the results to HDFS. Versions are the following:

1. `Hadoop` `2.7.3`
2. `Spark` `2.2.0`
3. `Java` `1.8`

The following is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer;

public class Spark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Streaming").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000));
        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("testStr");

        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> stream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        ssc,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, byte[]>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                );
        stream.map(record -> finall(record.value())).map(record -> Arrays.deepToString(record)).dstream().saveAsTextFiles(
                "spark", "txt"
        );

        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();

    }

    public static String[][] finall(byte[] record){

        String[][] result = new String[4][];
        result[0] = javaTest.bytePrintable(record);
        result[1] = javaTest.hexTodecimal(record);
        result[2] = javaTest.hexToOctal(record);
        result[3] = javaTest.hexTobin(record);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

But neither on HDFS nor on local filesystem it errors:

`ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics.getThreadStatistics()Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsData;`

What's the issue? Is it needed to import some libraries from Hadoop?

**UPDATE**

Instead of Maven dependencies, I use local spark jars and it works. So something in dependencies is wrong. Following are `POM.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which one is incompatible? Or maybe something is missing!